# xcopy /exclude issue

Tags: windows, batch-file, xcopy

I am trying to run xcopy that copies files excluding .obj, etc.
What I am seeing is that Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder.dll is not copied when my excludes.txt file contains .obj as an extension. When .obj is removed, I Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder.dll is copied correctly. This does not happen to other dlls though.

Does anyone have any idea why this would happen?

Thanks!

Lenik

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I guess because the substring .obj is found in the name Microsoft.Practices**.Obj**ectBuilder.dll and since windows is not case sensitive, it will exclude it.

Comment: thanks André! MS Doc contradicts what's actually happening:

"If you specify the string ".obj", you exclude all files with the .obj extension."
curious if there is a way to get around the issue...

Comment: WHere are you copying from that you see .obj files?

Comment: I am copying from the root directory recursively -- I need to include .asmx, .configs etc, but I want to skip intermediate files.

Answer (score 6):

Yeah, xcopy is dumb like that.

Do this:

```
dir /b *.obj >excludes.txt
xcopy * /exclude:excludes.txt targetdir
```

although this will still have the problem sometimes.

If you had a file called **practices.ob**j, for example, it wouldn't copy that, but it would also fail to copy your Microsoft.**Practices.Obj**ectBuilder.dll

A handy trick is if you specify /s on dir, you get recursion *and* the full path, then if you specify the source directory fully on the xcopy, the excludes will have to match from the beginning:

```
dir /s /b *.obj >excludes.txt
xcopy c:\sourcedir\* /exclude:excludes.txt \targetdir
```

Now Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder.dll would only fail to copy if you happen to have a Microsoft.Practices.obj file in the same directory. Get it?

Answer (score 3):

XCOPY is [deprecated](http://blogs.msdn.com/matt_pietrek/archive/2007/01/16/robocopy-built-into-vista.aspx) now anyway, so I doubt things are going to get fixed.  Take a look at ROBOCOPY - it's built into Vista, and comes in the resource kit for [2003 and XP](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=9d467a69-57ff-4ae7-96ee-b18c4790cffd&displaylang=en).

Answer (score -3):

The answer is what you could obtain by typing:

```
xcopy /?
```

Namely:

> /EXCLUDE:file1[+file2][+file3]...
>                Specifies a list of files containing strings.  Each string
>                should be in a separate line in the files.  When any of the
>                strings match any part of the absolute path of the file to be
>                copied, that file will be excluded from being copied.  For
>                example, specifying a string like \obj\ or .obj will exclude
>                all files underneath the directory obj or all files with the
>                .obj extension respectively.

Comment: @gizmo - to be fair to Lenik, from the xcopy /exclude help text I wouldn't have said RTFM made it any clearer, especially that last sentence which is being quite specific from my reading of it. "any part of the absolute path" does not necessarily equate to any part of filename.

Comment: Yeah great! So I'm being downvoted just because people are unable to understand a 5 lines explanation. Stackoverflow is getting worth and worth over time... and still in beta.